# Creating progress monitor for Apache Camel's FTP component

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am trying to configure Apache Camel's FTP to print more information as it work:

- "Connecting to FTP" when trying to connect to FTP server
- Should log "Starting the process of downloading from FTP " if can successfully connect and download process starts
- Should print progress every 5 seconds "Downloading in progress...". Ideally should print the downloaded size if possible
- Should print "File downloaded successfully" when FTP download is done

But the problem is I could not find any "hooks" to do so. Is it even possible?